# Can i use selenium for desktop application automation by connecting to remote computer through a browser?

Tags: testing, selenium, browser, automation, desktop

I got a doubt that if selenium only works for web applications,then if we connect to a desktop through a web browser,does selenium helps to do automation testing for a desktop applications as well?PL clarify my doubt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one of my previous positions we had similar case. So about that

> I got a doubt that if selenium only works for web applications

In the [Seleniumhq](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) site, in the very first line you'll find that

> Selenium automates browsers.

More info is available about the [JsonWireProtocol](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol), that is used by Selenium.

However a workaround could be - record via browser's web site required info (e.g. commands, interactions ) and pass them to a remote VM for processing. But on that VM you'll have to find how

> to do automation testing for a desktop applications

-in other words...what framework to use this already gathered info for the desktop's app automation.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium is all about executing JavaScripts on browsers. It opens browser, execute JavaScripts as per your instruction, e.g. click, search element, move mouse, enterText, etc, etc. When you take any computer remote via your browser, you might be using third party plugin, e.g. flash player, shockwave player, MS silver light, join.me app as plugin, citrix plugin, etc, with your brwoser. These plugins can not be controled by JavaScript, hence can not be controled by selenium as well. Even if you work with coordinates, you may not have reliable solution in place.

Comment: Thank you Mayur shah.got a clarification

Answer (score 0):

In theory, you can. However, you need to deal with screen 
coordinate (x,y) for step execution and image comparison for check point.

Comment: could you please elaborate your lines of comment @ nguyen vu hoang .i am completely new to selenium.thank you for your reply